# Funding is from TA - What to put for funding acknowledgment

Tags: publications, funding

Most journals require you to state your funding sources. I am a current phd candidate, submitting a paper as sole author, and my funding currently comes from a teaching assistantship, which is paid for by the department, not my advisor. I feel that people usually list any grants/awards in their funding acknowledgment. What am I supposed to put? "Supported by department X in X university?"

Comment: I have seen papers say "No particular funding supported this research." You should check with your advisor

Comment: Do you have other financial support for your research? Computer, desk/office, other support personnel?

Comment: I have an office and laptop, but those are also paid for by the department and not my advisor.

Comment: Then at a minimum I'd credit the department for funding.

Comment: If the department is your affiliation on the paper, then I don't think it's necessary to separately acknowledge it for the office and computer.

Answer (score 3):

A TA doesn't directly fund your research. It funds you, personally and allows you to be a student. Your research hasn't been funded specifically other than the fact that you may have an office, etc. There is probably a tuition waiver, which is a sort of general funding.

You could list the department and university generally as you suggest. You could probably also list "none", but the department might be the better option.